# How do I host a mintty shell inside of Console2?

Tags: shell, console, console2

I like to use [Console2](http://console.sf.net) for my Windows shell work, where I usually make it open a cygwin bash prompt.

I'd like to try out MinTTY (2), and want to host it within Console2 as well.  If this is possible, how do I do it?

I've set Console2 to have a tab that fires

```
C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -
```

but this removes the Console2 window and creates a MinTTY one that is not visible.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can not do that.

Console2 (being a "Terminal Emulator") hosts terminal programs .. as in "hey, I will render the chars you want to output and I will give you what the user types into the keyboard". Useful terminal programs mostly used in "Terminal Emulators" are "Shells", such as "cmd.exe" or "powershell.exe" or "bash.exe" or "zsh.exe". If you like it, you could also host "python.exe" from within Console2.

Mintty is also a "Terminal Emulator". For that reason, you can not do what you are asking for.

Just to explain the used 'terms' (hehe) a bit more:

- [Terminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal): "The function of a terminal is confined to display and input of data ... A text terminal, or often just terminal (sometimes text console) is a serial computer interface for text entry and display." Back in the good old days these "terminals" were really hardware and looked like:

  [image]
- [Terminal Emulator:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator) "A terminal emulator, terminal application, term, or tty for short, is a program that emulates a "dumb" video terminal within some other display architecture. Though typically synonymous with a command line shell or text terminal, the term terminal covers all remote terminals, including graphical interfaces."
- [Shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing)): "A shell is a piece of software that provides an interface for users to an operating system..."

Comment: More precisely, Console2 *is a terminal* (and so is MinTTY).

Comment: indeed. i .. tried to improve the answer :)

Answer (score 5):

You cannot host MinTTY, but you can use directly the Cygwin bash as the Console2 shell. Just create a new tab with \bin\bash.exe --login -i as your shell

Comment: While this works, it seems to break support for mouse. For instance, in Cygwin's mintty.exe, I can use the mouse to click around Midnight Commander. However, when running bash directly, mouse doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I just did it with this procedure => http://blog.jaykanakiya.com/terminal-setup-in-windows-7/

Change Default Settings of Console2

Right-click -> Edit -> Settings.

Console:
Shell: C:\cygwin64\Cygwin.bat
Startup Directory: H:/ [your daily workspace]